# Variables with function scope

Tags: c#, exception, garbage-collection

How the CLR handles local variables with function scope in case an exception is thrown.
is it a must to use the finally block or the variable is disposed once the flow leaves the function

below is a small example

```
    protected void FunctionX()
    {
        List<Employee> lstEmployees;
        try
        {
           lstEmployees= new List<Employee>();
           int s =  lstEmployees[1].ID; // code intended to throw exception
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ManageException(ex, ShowMessage); //exception is thrown here
        }
        finally { lstEmployees= null; } // Is the finally block required to make sure the list is cleaned
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your specific question, no, the `finally` block you've listed is not required.

Assigning `null` to a reference variable does not actually *do* anything, as garbage collection is non-deterministic. As a simplistic explanation, from time to time, the garbage collector will examine the objects within the heap to determine if there are any active references to them (this is called being "rooted"). If there are no active references, then these references are eligible for garbage collection.

Your assignment to `null` is not required, as once the function exits, the `lstEmployees` variable will fall out of scope and will no longer be considered an active reference to the instance that you create within your `try` block.

There *are* certain types (both within .NET and in third-party libraries) that implement the `IDisposable` interface and expose some deterministic cleanup procedures through the `Dispose()` function. When using these types, you should *always* call `Dispose()` when you're finished with the type. In cases where the lifetime of the instance shouldn't extend outside of the lifetime of the function, then you can use a `using() { }` block, but this is only required if the type implements `IDisposable`, which `List<T>` (as you used in your example) does not.

Comment: It's also interesting to note that the GC is allowed to be quite aggressive.  It may collect the memory for an instance even if you don't set it to null, as long as the compiler/jitter has determined that the reference will no longer be used.  This even applies to methods on the instance, so if you have a method on a class and that method is the last method you ever call on that instance, the instance is eligible for collection as soon as the method stops making use of 'this'.

Comment: @Dan: Exactly; nice examples.

Answer (score 3):

Don't be worried about the objects cleanup, that's why the .NET and most modern languages provide the garbage collection functionality in runtime.

If your object has a handle to unmanaged resource do that cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the other answers are slightly misleading here.

In fact, the garbage collector has got (almost) nothing to do with the variable `lstEmployees`. But it **never** needs to be set to `null`, neither in normal code flow nor after an exception is thrown.

Setting references to `null` to free the object they point they point to is almost *never* required, especially not for local objects.

As a consequence, the garbage collector won’t care about the exception either.

On the other hand, *unmanaged* resources which aren’t handled by the CG *do* always require manual cleanup (via the `Dispose` method of the `IDisposable` interface). To make sure that such resources are returned after an exception was thrown, you indeed need the `finally` clause. Or, if you don’t intend to handle the exception locally, you can replace the `try … finally` by a `using` clause:

```
using (someUnmanagedResource) {
    // … use the resource …
}
// Will implicitly call someUnmanagedResource.Dispose() *whatever happens*!
```

Comment: What about my answer is misleading...?

Comment: @Adam I could have sworn your answer talked about how the GC handles `finally` here. Your answer is fine. The other answers either imply this or fail to mention that `finally` doesn’t do anything special here and that `null` assignment isn’t needed here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

.NET languages are garbage collected, which means that objects lifetimes are kept track of, so the garbage collection will get rid of your list when it finds no more object references to it.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all. When the variable is out of scope, the garbage collector will take care of it (when the GC decides it's time to collect all the garbage...)

The only thing you have to take in account is that maybe you don't want to wait for the GC to do its job, so resources help by an instance of a class are released (e.g. imagine you have locally created an instance that hols a reference to a database connection. The connection will be held until GC takes care of deleting the instance, and later on deleting the referenced connection, which may take a while).

In these cases, take a look at the IDisposable interface, so you can proactively free resources before your instances are removed by the GC.

Comment: Just to be clear, calling `Dispose()` on an object that implements `IDisposable` is not a choice of whether or not you want the GC to clean it up or if you want it cleaned up explicitly. The pattern around `IDisposable` says that you're *required* to call `Dispose()` when the instance is no longer needed.

Comment: @Adam Robinson - You're right, I dind't explain it correctly. I was just trying to note that if you need to clean up resources and don't want to wait until GC calls your object finalizer, you can implement the IDisposable interface pattern. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

.NET's garbage collector will handle this for you. In fact, setting "lastEmployees" to null accomplishes the same thing as just exiting the function.

Any item that is no longer referenced by the root application in one form or another will be marked for collection.

In .NET, you never need to worry about cleaning up managed resource. Hence, managed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx.aspx